# Python: IndexError: list index out of range and Class objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, error-handling

[image]

I hope to 2-D list. And each element in the list is set to unique class object. But I get the error(please see the screenshot). How can I get it done? Thank you!

Comment: 1. All code must be included as _text_ in your question. 2. All errors and tracebacks must be included as text in your question. Images are the easy way out, but make your question difficult to search for and answer.

Comment: I don't know how to assign class objects into the list. How should I do? Any idea?

Comment: I need Vertion[0][1] not equal to Vertion[1][1]. How to create unique objects in each elements?

Comment: you did not respond to my previous comment, and have not updated your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here before you assigning values to 2-d array Vertion you have to create an empty list with the exact number of rows and columns you want. Then only you can assign values to each each columns in each rows. Here you can take a look :

```
Vertion = [[0 for x in range(128)] for y in range(2)]
```

**Update :**

So for assign values to columns in each rows you can try like this :

```
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(128):
        Vertion[i][j] = Block()
```

Comment: But I cannot assign class objects into the list. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Vertion = [[], []]
```

as Vertion is a list with two empty list, so the for loop should be like this

```
for i in range(len(Vertion)):
    for j in range(128):
        Vertion[i].append(Block())
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Thank you!

Comment: But this method cannot create unique object. I do not want Vertion[0][1]==Vertion [1][1]. I need Vertion[0][1] != Vertion [1][1]. How to solve this question? Thank you!

Comment: @Yifei what the unique means? post your code , Vertion[0][1] shouldn't equal with Vertion[1][1]